# ¿Se puede añadir líneas a dos listas distintas con una sola ejecución del comando find de linux?

Tags: linux, find

En un equipo *linux* tengo esta estructura de archivos:

```
test
├── dir1
│   └── fi1.txt
├── dir2
│   └── fi2.txt
└── fi0.txt
```

Quiero separar nombres de directorios y archivos en dos listas, ejecutando una sola instancia de *find*, en los archivos *dir.ls* y *fi.ls*, respectivamente

`find test -type d -fprint dir.ls , -type f -fprint fi.ls`

El problema llega a la hora de **añadir** líneas a esas listas **en una sola ejecución** de *find*. He probado lo siguiente:

`find test -type d -exec echo {} >> dir.ls \; , -type f -exec echo {} >> fi.ls \;`

con resultados inesperados (guarda todo en el 2º archivo).
¿Es posible conseguirlo con una sola ejecución de *find*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una manera de hacerlo es que no sea `find` quien determine si son o no directorios, sino `bash`:

```
find test/ -name '*' -exec bash -c "test -d '{}' && echo '{}' >> dir.ls || echo '{}' >> fi.ls" \;
```

El comando `test -d`  es exitoso sólo cuando el argumento que se le envía es un directorio. En ese caso, envía el resultado a `dir.ls`, y, en caso contrario (un archivo), lo envía a `fi.ls`. Si hay otro tipo de archivos además de carpetas y directorios, habría que agregar la prueba `test -f`.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el siguiente comando:

```
find test \( -type d -fprintf dir.ls '%p\n' \) , \( -type f -fprintf fi.ls'%p\n' \)
```

Si solo quieres los nombres cambia *%p* por *%f*.